# Using Visual Studio Code on MacOS "Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided."

Tags: macos, terminal, high-sierra

### **Scenario/Setup:**

- MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6 with new install of VSCode 1.50.0
- Following/running VSCode Node Tutorial from:   https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-tutorial
- Jump to "[Express Application](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-tutorial#_an-express-application)" section

  1. install **Express** as directed using `npm install -g express-generator`
  2. build app as directed using `express myExpressApp --view pug`
  3. run app using `npm start` but app / web server fails to run with error in terminal

### **Error:**

> `Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.`

### **System Details:**

- New install of VSCode 1.50.1
  [image]
- MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6
  [image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 1):

Seems that **pug** view rendering engine NOT INSTALLED locally as a depency, even though I installed **Express** globally with `npm install -g express-generator`

### Fix

1. run a terminal window, or press `` CTRL-` ``(backtick) from inside of **Visual Studio Code**
2. `cd` into your project directory/folder - or already there if launched the terminal from VSCode (previous step)... from there run these commands:

   1. install pug as a local dependency with `npm install pug`
   2. for EXTRA good measure, re-install express locally with: `npm install express`
   3. ensure all dependencies are installed and updated using: `npm install`
   4. relaunch your application with:   `npm start`
   5. test/view your application at: http://localhost:3000